# Hibernate issue with delete entire table and then bulk insert

Tags: hibernate

Team,

I am facing one strange issue with hibernate. where I am seeing lots of delete happening.

e.g.When I run below code expectation is it will delete the data from EMPLOYEE table and then do the bulk insertion.

```
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();



        String stringQuery = "DELETE FROM Employee";
        Query query = session.createQuery(stringQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();

        session.flush();
        session.clear();

        Employee employee = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {
            Employee = employeeList
                    .get(i);
            session.save(employee);
        }

        tx.commit();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();

    }

    finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }

    }
```

But when we enable show SQL there are "N" number of deletes are happening and it seems it is sequentially after all insert.

I kept a debugger on tx.commit() and following is the outcode for Show-sql

e.g. It seems it is going in infinite loop with same set of statement.

delete from employee 
insert into employee values 
delete from employee 
insert into employee values 
delete from employee 
insert into employee values

Comment: Can you show your configuration file & mapping file / POJO with annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is going in infinite loop? and well you do not need to `flush` and `clear` session before, hibernate will fire query in synchronize manner only it will delete your records first and then will go to insert new. Put `flush` and `clear` statement after `commit`

And one more thing you do not need to iterate loop and insert one by one record you can use `saveOrUpdateAll` method to bulk insert records.